# Extracting String from Column

Tags: r, string

I am working with the following dataset called results and am trying to add in a column that only contains the date (ideally just the year) of the row.

[image]

I am trying to extract just the date (for example: 2012-02-10) from the column_label column.

This is the code that I use:

```
pattern <- "- (.*?) .RData"

subsetpk <- results %>%
  filter(team=="Pakistan") %>%
  mutate(year = str_extract(column_label, pattern))
```

This, however, only gives me NA values.

Comment: Try this : `as.Date(gsub("\\D+", '', df$column_label), '%Y%m%d')`

Comment: Use a snipped of data instead of a picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regular expression.  Here '\\d{4}' just matches the first 4 consecutive digits that are found in the string.  This works if your data always looks the same as your example.  If not, you may need something more sophisticated.  If this doesn't work, post some more example data.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)



 df <- data.frame(column_label = c("Afghanistan-Pakistan-2012-02-10.RDATA.overs",
                                  "Afghanistan-Pakistan-2019-02-10.RDATA.overs"))

df %>% 
  mutate(my_year = str_extract(column_label, '\\d{4}'))

                                 column_label my_year
#1 Afghanistan-Pakistan-2012-02-10.RDATA.overs    2012
#2 Afghanistan-Pakistan-2012-02-10.RDATA.overs    2019
```

Answer (score 1):

The `ymd()` function from the `lubridate` package

> Transforms dates stored in character and numeric vectors to Date or POSIXct objects

So, we can pass the complete string conveniently *without* having to deal with regular expressions:

```
x <- c("Afghanistan-Pakistan-2012-02-10.RDATA.overs",
       "Afghanistan-Pakistan-2019-02-10.RDATA.overs")

lubridate::ymd(x)
```

> ```
> [1] "2012-02-10" "2019-02-10"
> ```

The year can be derived from the extracted dates by

```
library(lubridate)
year(ymd(x))
```

> ```
> [1] 2012 2019
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Use `str_extract` from the package `stringr`:

**DATA**:

```
results <- data.frame(
  column_label = "Afghanistan-Pakistan-2012-02-10.RData.overs")
```

**SOLUTION**:

```
results$date <- str_extract(results$column_label, "\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}")
```

**RESULT**:

```
results
                                 column_label       date
1 Afghanistan-Pakistan-2012-02-10.RData.overs 2012-02-10
```